# SAS proc tabulate outputs column total

Tags: sas

I have two indexes for serveral cities and I want to output a summary.

Here's my code

```
proc tabulate data=HAVE missing;
class Date City/order=data preloadfmt;
format City $Areaformat.;
var Index1 Index2;
table (Date=''),
      (Index1={Label="AAA" s=[cellwidth=2in just=c]}*(sum='') Index2={Label="BBB" s=[cellwidth=2in 
      just=c]}*(sum='')) * (City='' all=Total);
run;
```

Here's the sample output.

```
                                  Index1                            Index2
                   City1    City2    City3    Total    City1     City2    City3    Total
01Nov2014            1        2        1        4        1         1        1        3  
02Nov2014            2        2        1        5        2         1        2        5
```

But I need something like

```
                                  Index1                            Index2                   Index Total
                   City1    City2    City3    Total    City1     City2    City3    Total     Grand Total
01Nov2014            1        2        1        4        1         1        1        3          7
02Nov2014            2        2        1        5        2         1        2        5          10
```

Also, I have another output from `proc tabulate` which shows the ideal index on each day.

```
proc tabulate data=Ideal missing;
class Date;
var Index1 Index2;
table (Date=''), 
      (Index1={Label="Ideal Index1"}*(sum='Total') Win={Index2="Ideal Index2"}*(sum='Total'));
run;
```

Here's another output.

```
                  Ideal1        Ideal2
                   Total         Total
01Nov2014            4            3  
02Nov2014            5            5
```

Is there a way to append the ideal indexes table to the right of desired output above (easier for comparison rather than seperate them into two output tables)? Finally to be like this

```
                      Index1                      Index2           Index Total  Ideal1  Ideal2  Ideal Total  Diff           
           City1  City2  City3  Total  City1  City2  City3  Total  Grand Total   Total  Total    Total     
01Nov2014   1      2      1       4      1      1      1      3         7          4      3       7            0
02Nov2014   2      2      1       5      2      1      2      5         10         5      5       10           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dtdate9 to format your datetime to date9. You may want multiple class statements since that won't be a preloadformat. Add another all at the end for the Grand Total.

```
proc tabulate data=HAVE missing;
class City/order=data preloadfmt;
class Date/order=data;
format City $Areaformat.;
format date dtdate9.;
var Index1 Index2;
table (Date=''),
      (Index1={Label="AAA" s=[cellwidth=2in just=c]}*(sum='') Index2={Label="BBB" s=[cellwidth=2in 
      just=c]}*(sum='')) * (City='' all=Total) all='Grand Total';
run;
```

Comment: why `dtdate9.` not `date9.`? And can I append the Ideal Indexes output to the right of cites' output?

Comment: dtdate9 is used for date times, date9 is used for date variables. If you want to use date9 then you'll have to convert it to a date variable in a different data step.  You can try and append it by simply adding that to your table statement after the all.  Without the code a bit hard to tell.

Comment: Add that to the previous table statement? But it's from another dataset.

Comment: I add `all = 'Grand Total` but it returns `N` instead of summation

Comment: If it's from another dataset then no you can't. You'd have to prepare the data ahead of time, either merge or append it in as necessary.